# Different angular module for administration area

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm here because I want to know if it is a good practice, make a different module for administration area. I have these modules app, app.controllers, app.directives, app.adm, app.adm.controllers, app.adm.services...

This is right? There is some another good way? What is your opinion about that? This is organized or unnecessary?

Comment: Please see http://blog.angularjs.org/2014/02/an-angularjs-style-guide-and-best.html as a resource from the angular team

Comment: It is so bad to use `app.ctrls`, `app.services`? I really think that this way are more embracing than the angular way (in this repository https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app), because in my case, I have two ways of "genres area" an administration genre area, and a user genre area, so I use app.genres and app.adm.genres. You know something that can help me?